# How can I reference a static range in an array formula to pull data in?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using an `ARRAYFORMULA` to pull in some data from a range.

If a certain condition is met, for a specific row/column, I want to pull in default values from a lookup table of sorts.

I have sheet ([sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eN7wpRcrUQJ5zmfY9aprBWUQpIKpgKRwwk4KfhJavxE/edit#gid=0)) with data like so:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  | default a | default b | default c |  |  |  |  |
| **2** |  | 2 | 3 | 4 |  |  |  |  |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **4** | # | a | b | c |  | caluldated a | calculated b | calculated c |
| **5** | 1 | 1 |  |  |  | #VALUE! |  |  |
| **6** | 2 |  |  |  |  | #VALUE! |  |  |
| **7** | 3 |  |  |  |  | #VALUE! |  |  |
| **8** | 4 |  |  |  |  | #VALUE! |  |  |
| **9** | 5 |  |  |  |  | #VALUE! |  |  |
| **10** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **11** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **12** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **13** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

My "lookup table" is `B$2:D$2`.

In `F5` I want to put an array formula that will:

- put values in `F5:H12`
- by checking values in `B5:D12`
- and:

  - if `B5:D12` is empty then put 0
  - else pull in the corresponding value from `B$2:D$2`

For example, if `C6` is not empty, then it should pull in `C$2`.

I am trying this formula but it gives an error:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
        $A5:$A12 <> "",
        IFS(
            B5:D12 = ""     , 0      ,
            TRUE           , B$2:D$2
        ),
    )
)
```

> IFS has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 5. column count: 3. Actual row count: 1, column count: 3.

It only gives the error when any cell in `B5:D12` is not empty. If all the cells in `B5:D12` are empty, then it properly puts 0 in `F5:H12`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `MAP()` function.

```
=MAP(B5:D12,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",0,INDEX(A2:D2,COLUMN(x)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B5:D12="",0,B2:D2))
```

[image]

If the values in `B2:D2` are numbers, you can ditch the `IF()` and use:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA((B5:D12<>"")*B2:D2)
```

[image]